# Actuator Health check in java for env endpoint is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Actuator endpoint of env is not working. Other end point such as health and info are worked.

I used management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* in application.yml, still getting 401 unauthorised

Comment: can you elaborate? any code snippets?

Comment: If you have spring security check if actuator is properly configured e.g. SecurityWebFilterChain

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rajeshb, let me check and fix it

Answer (score 0):

Actuator endpoints require authentication by default.

You need to provide correct credentials to access the endpoints or you can disable security for all Spring Boot Actuator endpoints:

```
management.security.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

in your configuration file.